# Calculating two standard deviations above the mean

Tags: descriptive-statistics

I have a variable a need to find data points which are two standard deviations above the mean.

Example, let say we have: 2, 3, 4, 120, 5.

Sample mean=26.11 Stan.deviation=52.11

I have been calculating something like: 2*52.11+26.11=131.02

I think I am missing something since the 120 is outside of normal distribution curve but if I use this calculation method the 120 is smaller than 131.02, which means that it is normally distributed.

Could anyone explain that to me?

Comment: Why do you think those points are normally distributed?

Comment: I mean it lies always below this value. I doesn't matter if it is 5000 or 10000 it still is smaller that my 2 standard deviation above the mean.

Comment: You either have a non-normal distribution or a normal distribution with a large outlier. Outliers can lead to a very inaccurate estimate of the population mean & the population variance. Also since all values between -infinity to +infinity the values 120 and 131.02 are both possible (although unlikely to occur in your example. Where a number lies with respect to + or - 2 times the the sample standard deviation away from the mean does not indicate or rule out that the sample comes from a normal distribution.

Comment: What actually can be said is that if the you have a normal distribution 95% of the distribution lies between the mean + or - 1.96 standard deviations.

Answer (score 1):

I think the criterion of having an observation exceed $\bar X + 2S$ is intended
as a way to highlight an observation as an "outlier." This criterion does
not work very well because the large observation 120 itself leads to
inflating both $\bar X$ and $S$ so that $\bar X + 2S$  is larger than it "should" be.

A better criterion might be to *delete* 120 before computing mean $\bar X^\prime$ and $S^\prime.$ Then you'd have $120 > 6.082.$ [Computation using R.]

```
x.d = c(2,3,4,5);  mean(x.d) + 2*sd(x.d)
[1] 6.081989
```

Another method is to use the interquartile range (IQR) as a 'robust' measure
of variability (which does not depend so crucially on any one observation).
That is the idea behind using boxplots to suggest possible outliers.

```
x = c(2, 3, 4, 120, 5)
boxplot(x, horizontal=T)
```

[image]

The boxplot 'outlier' rule is to suggest any observation above
$Q_3 + 1.5\text{IQR}$ as a high outlier, where $Q_3$ is the third quartile.
Similarly, any observation below $Q_1 - 1.5\text{IQR}$ is suggested
as a possible low outlier.

All outlier criteria need to be used with great caution because
some distributions routinely have 'outliers'--especially in large
samples. Almost all samples of size 100 from an exponential distribution
have 'outliers'. More specifically, for the simulation below about 99%  of
exponential samples of size 100 had at least one outlier and the average
number of outliers per sample was nearly 5.

```
nr.out = replicate(10^5, length(boxplot.stats(rexp(100))$out))
mean(nr.out)
[1] 4.84265
mean(nr.out > 0)
[1] 0.99023
```

Even among samples of size 100 from a normal distribution, over 90%
have at least one 'boxplot outlier'--but usually only one or two of them
per sample. Generating such a sample with today's date as seed, I happened to get three 'outliers'.

```
set.seed(1116); x = rnorm(100)
boxplot(x, horizontal=T)
```

[image]

Comment: This method is used to detect currency crises. Most of researchers use this method but can't get how this is done since a large number would increase mean and standard deviation, so it makes almost impossible to detect the large jumps in the EMP (Exchange market pressure index).